# PDOException occurs while trying to run php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, exception, terminal, laravel-5

**[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**

I am trying to Run **php artisan migrate** command using terminal.
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your trying to use an sqlite database that does not exist. If this is the case create a new `database/database.sqlite` empty file and try again.

Comment: thanks for the response.
But where i have to create this folder?

Comment: In the root of your project you should have the database folder which contains your migrations, seeds and factories. In that same folder create the database.sqlite file.

Comment: my project name is testing ...Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:projects ahsanulhaq$ cd testing
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:testing ahsanulhaq$ php artisan migrate

                                                    
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: its is giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP be sure to add the unix_socket key with a value of the path that the mysql.sock resides in MAMP.

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Comment: i am too beginner in laravel. I don't know about it. Can you please help me more?

Comment: yes... I tried it while i am in the project directory. it is giving the same answer

Comment: i am using xampp.  How to do these changing?